# File observer not working in android 10 and higher

Tags: java, android, file, android-10.0

My requirement was to observe one of the user's file even if the app is not running in the background, so I created a foreground service (nice and easy) and placed the file observer code in it and of course, I handled the following warning

> Warning: If a `FileObserver` is garbage collected, it will stop sending
> events. To ensure you keep receiving events, you must keep a reference
> to the FileObserver instance from some other live object.

by placing the `FileObserver` variable in `App.class`

**And it is working fine up to android 9 perfectly as expected but when I tried my app on android 10 I could see the foreground service running but whenever observed file got modified, no event gets fired**

I read some new restrictions on `java.io.file` from android 10 but I'm not able to get my desired result.

**Is there any way or alternative to get around this bug?**

code

```
private void startObserving() {
        fileObserver = new FileObserver(utilityClass.GET_X_FOLDER().getPath(), FileObserver.ALL_EVENTS) {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(int event, @Nullable String path) {
                if (event == FileObserver.CREATE) {
                    start(path);
                }
            }
        };
        fileObserver.startWatching();
    }
```

manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.ss_app">

    <application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".Help" />
        <activity android:name=".developer"/>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".AlaramReceiver" />
        <receiver android:name=".BootBroadCastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".FileDeleteService" />
        <service android:name=".ForeGroundService" />
        <service android:name=".xService" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="xxxx"/>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_FULL_SCREEN_INTENT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

</manifest>
```

Comment: There is a chat feature in stackOverflow but I can't seem to use it. In any case, I just ran another test on Android 10 and it's working. I had to add the line * 
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"* under the <application> tag in the manifest.xml file. Check to see if it's working

Comment: thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu boy. You have my life @DanBaruch adding the line you said. Everything worked fine. Just thank you. Now if you don't mine I was to be your friend I mean on any social network do you have any

Comment: I see haha, in that case just hit me up here when ever you need. I'll delete my other comments to prevent this from being so long

Comment: i will also @DanBaruch

Comment: hey @DanBaruch i need you again https://stackoverflow.com/q/65263749/14599955

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution: just add the following line under your application tag in manifest**

```
 android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

Comment: yes, it worked for me, but not in android 11.

Comment: Any solution for android 11 ?

Comment: not yet, if you find any, please do let me know here.

Comment: but it will only work in android 10, for android 11 you need to ask permission to read and write files, which you can find on google. But then you have to also give a reason to play the store while publishing ur app that why you need that permission. And they don't usually agree with developers  statement and need

Answer (score 0):

Also be sure to go in to Settings->Apps->YourApp and grant Storage permission if you aren't requesting it dynamically in your app.